# Select string to display only a certain part of a returned line

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to get piped select-string commands in Powershell to return only what I'm searching for, plus some extra information at the end. Here is what I have so far:

```
PS H:\> gwmi win32_LoggedOnUser -computer server | select-string -pattern "domain" | select-string -pattern "Admin" -NotMatch

\\server\root\cimv2:Win32_LoggedOnUser.Antecedent="\\\\.\\root\\cimv2:Win32_Account.Domain=\"domain\",Name=\"user1\"",Dependent="\\\\.\\root\\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=\"44946387\""
\\server\root\cimv2:Win32_LoggedOnUser.Antecedent="\\\\.\\root\\cimv2:Win32_Account.Domain=\"domain\",Name=\"user2\"",Dependent="\\\\.\\root\\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=\"41485153\""
\\server\root\cimv2:Win32_LoggedOnUser.Antecedent="\\\\.\\root\\cimv2:Win32_Account.Domain=\"domain\",Name=\"user3\"",Dependent="\\\\.\\root\\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=\"46401036\""
\\server\root\cimv2:Win32_LoggedOnUser.Antecedent="\\\\.\\root\\cimv2:Win32_Account.Domain=\"domain\",Name=\"user4\"",Dependent="\\\\.\\root\\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=\"40161073\""
\\server\root\cimv2:Win32_LoggedOnUser.Antecedent="\\\\.\\root\\cimv2:Win32_Account.Domain=\"domain\",Name=\"user5\"",Dependent="\\\\.\\root\\cimv2:Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=\"46557830\""
```

So I've got what I'm looking for but I want to shorten up what the command actually shows me. Preferably I would like to see only:

```
Domain\user1
Domain\user2
```

But I do not know how to do this. The closest I have come is by piping another command 'Select Matches' onto the end. I have read that regex may be the answer to my troubles.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use something like below:

```
(gwmi win32_LoggedOnUser) | %{[void]($_.Antecedent -match 'Domain="(\w+)",Name="(\w+)"'); "{0}\{1}" -f $matches[1],$matches[2]}
```

---

Avoid using so many `select-string` - that is like bash with all the grep, sed, awk, cut voodoo which I believe Powershell avoids with high fidelity objects. Try to use the Objects and their properties as much as possible. Yes it is not always possible to use them and we resort to `select-string` or other string manipulations, but try to avoid them till the last possible step. Makes Powershell programming neat, simple and bug-free IMO.

Answer (score 0):

See if this gives you what you want:

```
gwmi win32_LoggedOnUser -computer server | select-string -pattern "domain" | select-string -pattern "Admin" -NotMatch | Select-Object @{n='Result'; e={$_ -match '.*Domain=\\"(\w*)\\.*Name=\\"(\w*)\\.*' | Out-Null; $matches[1] + '\' + $matches[2]}}
```

Comment: Very nice! Does exactly what I wanted! Now to pick it apart and figure out how you did it...

Comment: Please read and accept manojlds' answer it is actually better and his comments are correct. I upvoted his answer because it is better than mine. I just left mine here simply because it shows a slightly different approach.